# Boot stuck at Prohibitory screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup, disk-utility

I'm using Macbook Pro 2012 running Mac OS X 10.10.3 and earlier today, I was trying to install Linux on a USB drive through Terminal.
I first converted the format with this:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ubuntu.iso ubuntu-1xxxx.iso
```

Next, listed drives with:

```
diskutil list
```

Added my flash drive.
And then ran this:

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN
```

where N being the no. of drive from the DiskUtil list.
Here by mistake I chose the `disk0`, my boot recovery in my opinion, and unmounted that.

After that I ran,

```
sudo dd if=./ubuntu.iso of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
```

where again N being the no of drive listed in DiskUtil list. Here again, absentmindedly I chose `disk1`, the Macintosh HD, in my opinion. And suddenly after that I realized, what was happening and cancelled the process midway.

After that I tried remounting my recovery, but my Mac froze and after I tried to restart i got stuck at the prohibitory page.
I tried booting into Recovery with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and tried mounting my Macintosh HD from there, but it gave me a error, that it couldn't be mounted. It asked me, to check a Disk Verification and Disk repair, I did that on my Macintosh HD and both were okay.
But after that also the problem persists and I can't mount the Macintosh HD and still stuck at the prohibitory page.

I want to save my data, and want to backup my Macintosh HD, to an external hard drive.

Comment: Hi @ritvik1512, Welcome to Ask Different. Please clarify your question, as it stands, it looks as a description of what you did –which probably is the cause of your computer refusing to boot– but it isn't clear what you would like to achieve. Would you like to save your data? Reinstall? Repairing or recovering a partially re-writen partition does not seem to be an easy route.

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz I'm looking for ways to backup my Macintosh HD.